# MySql Inner Join not displaying Data in Google Chart

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I'm a complete newbie and trying to make a visualization of a survey I've put to managers and job applicants.  I'm trying to display the results as a line chart in Google Charts, with the manager and applicant input on the Y Axis, with the topics that they were asked about on the X Axis.  I've used an inner join to pull their answers into one table and put the topics as rows and manager and applicant answers as columns.  But it will not display the results and I get an 'Undefined variable' error when I inspect the page.

```
      <?php include "db.php";?> 
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['experience', 'strengths', 'cultural_fit'],
          <?php
            $query="select p.output, sum(case when r.candname = 'manager' 
then s.answer else 0 end) as Manager, sum(case when r.candname = 
'applicant01' then s.answer else 0 end) as Applicant01 from questions p 
inner join graphtable s on p.q_id = s.q_id inner join applied r on 
s.candidate = r.candidate group by p.output";
            $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            while($data= mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                $year=$data['experience'];
                $sale=$data['strengths'];
                $expense=$data['cultural_fit'];

          ?>
            ['<?php echo $experience;?>',<?php echo $strengths;?>,<?php 
echo $cultural_fit;?>],
          <?php
               }

          ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Score comparison',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new 
google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have three tables:

1. applied

```
candidate | candname
-----------------------
1           manager
2           applicant01
```

2. questions

```
q_id      | output
---------------------
1           experience
2           strengths
3           cultural_fit
```

3. graphtable (yeah, I know I'm terrible at naming stuff - working on this until the early hours didn't help)

```
candidate | answer |  q_id
     1        7       1
     1       20       2
     1       14       3
     2        9       1
     2       22       2
     2       18       3
```

I'd really appreciate any help you can provide - thanks in advance! Especially grateful for answers in the most simple terms possible!

Comment: The columns in the query are `output`, `Manager`, and `Applicant01`, but you're fetching `experience`, `strengths`, and `cultural_fit`. Then you're assigning them to variables named `$year`, `$sale`, and `$expense`, but echoing different variables.

Comment: `experience`, `strengths`, and `cultural_fit` aren't column names, they're the values of `$data['output']` on different rows.

Answer (score 0):

You're pivoting the results so that each applicant is in a different column. But in your visualization you want each question to be a column. So the query should be:

```
SELECT a.candname,
       SUM(CASE WHEN q.output = 'experience' THEN g.answer END) AS experience,
       SUM(CASE WHEN q.output = 'strengths' THEN g.answer END) AS strengths,
       SUM(CASE WHEN q.output = 'cultural_fit' THEN g.answer END) AS cultural_fit
FROM questions AS q
JOIN graphtable AS g ON q.q_id = g.q_id
JOIN applied AS a ON a.candidate = g.candidate
GROUP BY g.candidate
```

Then you need to set the correct variable names after you fetch:

```
            while($data= mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                $candname = $data['candname']
                $experience=$data['experience'];
                $strengths=$data['strengths'];
                $cultural_fit=$data['cultural_fit'];
                echo json_encode([$candname, $experience, $strengths, $cultural_fit]) . ",";
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar! So making your changes, I am able to visualize the graph.  But, two issues: 1.  the x and y axis are the wrong way around.  2.  It is plotting the outputs of cultural fit and strengths against experience.  Any ideas on how to address these?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the visualization API you're using. But for problem 2 you need to add the candidate names as the first element in each array.